# runner:streak_run shows unexpected result when k remains unchanged

Tags: r

I'm using runner:streak_run to count sequences of 0 and 1 in a column called "inactive_indicator".
The column is= 0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1

For `runner::streak_run(inactive_indicator))` 
I get the following:
1,2,3,1,2,3,1,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,1,2,3,4

Why is it stuck on 5 when it should go up to 8?
In documentation it says that k - running window size. By default window size equals length(x). Allow varying window size specified by vector of length(x)

As I understand, the default definition should be enough.
Problem resolves and I get expected results when running: 
`runner::streak_run(inactive_indicator),k=length(inactive_indicator))`

Why doesn't it work in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with `rle` from `base R`

```
sequence(rle(inactive_indicator)$lengths)
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4
```

---

Checked with `runner`

```
runner::streak_run(inactive_indicator)
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4
```

It is possible that there are some leading/lagging spaces in the column and it is not `numeric`.  In that case, use `trimws`

```
runner::streak_run(trimws(inactive_indicator))
```

#### data

```
inactive_indicator <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
```

Comment: Thanks! It is numeric and it does work when k=length(inactive_indicator). I just don't understand why it doesn't work without it.